# Mock Service into Service with Mockito and JUNIT and CDI

Tags: junit, mocking, mockito, cdi

I have 3 services

```
class Service1{
    @Inject private Service2 service2;

}
 class Service2{
    @Inject private Service3 service3;

}
class Service3{
    
 public Object test(){
 ...}

}

 class TestService1{
    //do a test and mock the method in service3 
   when(service3.test()).doReturn(Something());


}
```

I have to mock the method in service 3 injected in service 2 which is injected in service 1
any idea? I have to test it directly like that I have no other way to do it.

Comment: You could use an alternative producer which produces your mocked objects. Alternate solution, but I am not sure whether it's possible in combination with CDI: Take a look at the annotations `@InjectMocks` & `@Mock`.

Comment: it is possible but combine mock and real inject is complicated

Comment: Did you take a look at [weld-junit](https://github.com/weld/weld-junit)? It allows you to test CDI in SE environment and has some support for mocking as well, it might fit your needs. Here is a [README bit](https://github.com/weld/weld-junit/tree/master/junit5#adding-mock-beans) that shows how it works in combination with Mockito.

Comment: not this problem in fact the service c is making REST query so it have to be mocked but found a solution, thanks !

Comment: i use arquillian, weld-junit is only CDI, i forget to mention we use too EJB and jaxrs and keycloak ... but thanks to you i found a solution

Answer (score 0):

As the last service is a call to a rest Service, i created an interface IServiceC then 2 implementations of it, one in the main/src/java, another in test/src/java and all services are returned hardcoded values. because the complexity here is to say ok i will inject all service but not the last, and tell to second layer i inject you but i mock you too etc...

very too complicated to manage, with a mock class implementation i don't have to cary about this topic, i use arquillian and all will be injected (i exclude from the war package the default implementation and add the mock implementation to the war)